# codeigniter session expires frequently

Tags: codeigniter, session

I'm using codeigniter for my app

what my problem is session is expiring even though user is active on the site.

These are the session settings.. i'm using DB session

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'edu_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

any solution for this.

help me i have to fix it

here is the codeigniter  [forum link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182755/)

Comment: Are you positive that the sessions are being saved to the database correctly?

Comment: I Don't know, But when i'm using more data in session if the dbsession option is enabled then only session working, otherwise its not working

Answer (score 12):

I've had issues with CI sessions expiring randomly.  Do you have AJAX or dynamic resources loading the session library?  If so, imagine this scenario:

I submit an ajax request (which passes in my CI session id with the cookie), and it returns the results, BUT I'm also submitting some other request (loading a dynamic image, another AJAX request, etc.) that immediately follows the first request.  The first request might trigger the 300 second "it's time to update" event, and pass back a new cookie, but the additional request is sending the old session id, right?

So, CodeIgniter says "hey you, you can't do that" and creates a new session, invalidating both cookies my browser now doesn't know what to do with.

Here's a forum link I posted a while back that goes into more detail:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/172415/

Comment: Thanks landons. my application  has many dynamic ajax call like what you explained. If you have solution for this please let me know. this is a serious issue in my application. Thanks

Comment: I'd extend the Session class, and write your own sess_destroy function that checks the INPUT::is_ajax_request() function to prevent normal session expiration for ajax requests.  Keep in mind that the sess_read function will return FALSE every time it calls the sess_destroy() function, so you'll need to override that too.  Want a working example?

Comment: Ya, give me a working example, so that i can do it quickly. Thanks

Comment: Hi @landons, seems the link you posted is dead, do you have a working example or another link to what you are describing above that works on CI 2.2-stable?  I've gotten the latest as of today, and the session is still being destroyed almost 3 years later.

Comment: @mtpultz, I don't, but my "fix" on current CI projects is to set the session rotation interval to the same value as the session expiration config.  Keep in mind that it's not a good fix for high-profile, highly security-conscious projects

Comment: Hi @landons, the project I'm on is actually a higher-security web application.  I'm in a bind now with a looming due date to figure this out now.  Maybe upgrading to CI v3.0 might solve this?

Comment: @mtpultz Hopefully... I didn't even know it was out.  I reported the bug back in early 2.0 days; never even got an acknowledgement from the CI team.

Comment: Development is progressing, BCIT just recently took it over from EllisLab, seems 3.0 will be released once the new Sessions library is ready.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Things change in 8 years :)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the first answer, there is a race condition in the session library which has since been somewhat mitigated in the latest versions of CodeIgniter, including the 'develop' branch.  This implements an isAjax check on session rotation, but it doesn't really fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 3):

are you sure that the session is destroyed? I think that it's just not getting updated as supposed and it creates a new one on every page request. (common Codeigniter's setting issue)

**here's my suggestions:**

double check your Application/Config/config.php file to ensure that the part of session domain looks like that if you host the site on the main directory:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "yourdomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']  = "var/sessions/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and like that if you host the site on a sub-directory:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "yourdomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']  = "siteSubDirectory/var/sessions/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and also make sure that the 2 directories are writable by fixing their permissions to 755 or so, and I strongly recommend that you enable database session, it's more secure and will help you find out the real problem by checking the session table. good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

I will add a workaround for this issue.
if an ajax call is made then do not update the session
extend the session class by adding this file to the libraries folder:

```
    class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * sess_update()
     *
     * @access    public
     * @return    void
     */
    public function sess_update()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        if ( ! $CI->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change ci_sessions table encode to MyISAM:
`ALTER TABLE`ci_sessions`ENGINE = MyISAM;`

Comment: this is what i need, do you know why not work for InnoDB? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove bellow line from **config.php**

```
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the cookie domain in ,/application/config/config.php

```
  PHP Code:
    $config['cookie_prefix']   = '';
    $config['cookie_domain']   = '.domainname.com';
    $config['cookie_path']     = '/';
    $config['cookie_secure']   = FALSE;
    $config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

cookie_domain as your host name, this resolve my session expire issue