# Codeigniter session expire so soon

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I set `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0` but session still expires and the user id, which I set when the user login, sets as **0**

Users generally use IE7 and Chrome.

Also `sess_time_to_update` is **300**

How can I solve this?

Comment: i think you also have same problem like this check this link            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856960/codeigniter-session-expires-frequently

Comment: store long term information that a user has logged in a **cookie** not session data. Holding session data for a long time, on a busy site, will be bothersome in temporary file space that is needed for **all** the active sessions. The files cannot be deleted until they expire.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the session last for two days

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = ((60*60)*24)*2;
```